# Помогите сверстать данный блок на Bootsrap

Tags: html, css

Не получается сверстать блок в красном квадрате, первые два элемента отображаются ровно с заголовком, а вот последние два съезжают под кнопку "Learn More".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.ag-service-name {
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.ag-service-text {
    margin-top: 25px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: block;
    color: #737373;
}
```

```
<section class="ag-our-service">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <h1 class="ag-title">Do you know we can provide for you ?</h1>
        <span class="ag-title-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et.Lorem ni ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, ed
                doi eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</span>
        <button class="ag-btn">Learn More</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img src="img/settings.png" alt="Management" class="ag-service-icon">
        <h3 class="ag-service-name">Management</h3>
        <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img src="img/pencil.png" alt="UI /UX Design" class="ag-service-icon">
        <h3 class="ag-service-name">UI /UX Design</h3>
        <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img src="img/diamond.png" alt="Logo / Branding" class="ag-service-icon">
        <h3 class="ag-service-name">Logo / Branding</h3>
        <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img src="img/animation.png" alt="Animation" class="ag-service-icon">
        <h3 class="ag-service-name">Animation</h3>
        <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Comment: может код скинешь, посмотреть

Comment: В описаний добавил код, спасибо за отклик)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь так подходит.

```css
.ag-service-name {
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.ag-service-text {
    margin-top: 25px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: block;
    color: #737373;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <section class="ag-our-service">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <h1 class="ag-title">Do you know we can provide for you ?</h1>
                    <span class="ag-title-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et.Lorem ni ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis cing elit, ed
                        doi eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</span>
                    <button class="ag-btn">Learn More</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img src="img/settings.png" alt="Management" class="ag-service-icon">
                    <h3 class="ag-service-name">Management</h3>
                    <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                        eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img src="img/pencil.png" alt="UI /UX Design" class="ag-service-icon">
                    <h3 class="ag-service-name">UI /UX Design</h3>
                    <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                        eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img src="img/diamond.png" alt="Logo / Branding" class="ag-service-icon">
                    <h3 class="ag-service-name">Logo / Branding</h3>
                    <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                        eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img src="img/animation.png" alt="Animation" class="ag-service-icon">
                    <h3 class="ag-service-name">Animation</h3>
                    <span class="ag-service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sitea amet, zixf conseit adipi cing elit, seddi do
                        eiusmod btdempor in didunt utlae ore etioe.Lorem ipsum new idolor</span>
                </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```